# Assign value to readonly property works with fixed value but not with variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework to create an index and have the following code:

```
var op = new CreateIndexOperation
    {
        Columns = { "COL_A", "COL_B", "COL_C" },
        IsUnique = true,
        Name = "INDEX_NAME",
        Table = "TABLE_NAME"
    });
```

This compiles and works as expected.  Trying to refactor this into the following method (simplified for this example):

```
private void AddIndex(params string[] columns)
{
    var op = new CreateIndexOperation
    {
        Columns = columns.ToList(),
        IsUnique = true,
        Name = "INDEX_NAME",
        Table = "TABLE_NAME"
    });
}
```

This method throws the following compiler error:

```
Property or Indexer 'IndexOperation.Columns' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

Looking at the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.model.indexoperation.columns(v=vs.113).aspx#P:System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.IndexOperation.Columns), this appears to be correct and the `Columns` property doesn't have a setter.  However, if this is the case, why does the first block of code not throw a compiler-error, but the second does where I am trying to set this value from a variable instead?

Comment: Are you sure the first code is being compiled at all?

Comment: The first code will compile but it will fail at runtime with "NullReferenceException".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when using the first code you´re using the [collection-initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb384062.aspx), whereby the second example uses a classic setter-approach (which of course doesn´t exist). This means in the first example you´re actually calling something like this:

```
var op = new CreateIndexOperation();
op.Columns.Add(...);
op.IsUnique = true;
op.Name = "INDEX_NAME";
op.Table = "TABLE_NAME";
```

As you can see you´re not *setting* the property, but instead you call a method on the object returned by the *getter*.

This of course assumes that `Columns` is initialized within the class´ constructor. Otherwise you´ll get a `NullReferenceException`.

The second code however compiles to this:

```
var op = new CreateIndexOperation();
op.Columns = columns.ToList();
op.IsUnique = true;
op.Name = "INDEX_NAME";
op.Table = "TABLE_NAME";
```

Comment: Oh, I had missed the difference in the columns declaration... +1